# ios camera out of focus

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

I use AVFoundation to make consecutive shots. Some of them are out of the focus, even though I use the mode `AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus`.

It seems that `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` makes a shot while camera is still focusing.
Just before making a shot I check if `AVCaptureDevice.adjustingFocus` is true, but it is always false.

How can I find out the proper time to make a shot? Or how can I know when the camera focus was adjusted?

Answer (score 3):

I have a long bug report about this and other similar properties not changing. The documentation from apple on this topic is mostly wrong.

A few tips. Make sure you have defined the area to use for focusing (my code not handy now so cannot give method name). Second, use KVM on that property but don't look at the value directly, rather set kvonto return old and new value so you can compare and examine values (this straight from apple on my bug report.

In my case I only focus once then take a series but imagine the kvo should let you know each time focus is achieved.

All in all Apple has done a really poor job coding and documenting this - its really not up to par with other frameworks (IMHO).